# Getting image to only be 100 percent of height of parent container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with users scaling images in a content editor.

If they drag large versions of lower resolution images into this full width div, they stretch horizontally and vertically and only the middle portion of the image is seen and is grainy.

I'm trying to make sure that any image placed into the `fullContent` div is centered and only the height of that div so that the width scales accordingly. Basically trying to make the whole image be centered but fully seen no matter the size

```css
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
overflow: hidden;
}

iframe{
height:100% !important;
width:100% !important;
}

.middle p{
max-height:100%;
margin-bottom:0;     
display: flex
}

img {
object-fit: scale-down;
width: 100%; 
margin:0 auto;
}

#fullContent{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
overflow: hidden;
}

#fullContent img{
object-fit: contain;
}

.fullContent {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto;
}

.fullContent > img{
min-width:100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
}

.my-container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
height: 100vh;
width:100vw;
}

.my-container .top.row, 
.my-container .row.bottom {
flex-shrink: 0;
}

.my-container>.top [class^="col-"],
.my-container>.bottom [class^="col-"] {
background-color: #778899  ;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}

.my-container>.middle {
flex-grow: 1;
padding:30px;
/*background-image: url('images/bg_green.svg');*/
background-size: cover;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid my-container d-flex h-100">
    <div class="row top">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="row" style="background-color: #778899;">
          <h2>top row</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">

        <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
            <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent">
                <p><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1900x2300"/></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Row Middle -->

    <div class="row bottom">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="row" style="background-color: #778899;">
          <h2>bottom row</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change your `background-size:cover` to `background-size: contain`. Background-size property [reference](https://cssreference.io/property/background-size/) and `background-position: center center`

Comment: so that actually affects a background image on row middle which I haven't added, but it is used sometimes. This is specifically for an image needing to fit in fullContent div

Comment: Ah sorry. You could do it the way I suggested if you make your image a background instead of using an img tag. Otherwise, I'd remove the paragraph tag and add `height="100%"` to the `<img>`. Width will be auto calculated.

Comment: AH ok, is there a way to do that with the <p> tag though? Everything saved in the system is wrapped in a <p> tag because it's using TinyMCE editor

Comment: Well the problem is that the image height is based on its parent. In this case <p> so you would have to make that specific tag `p {display:block; height: 100%}` before your image will fill `#fullContent`

Comment: Ok I made those changes to the p tag but it still seems to be taller than it's parent #fullContent. I think that's the issue. If I can get the paragraph to only be contained to #fullContent then the image 100% height should work

Comment: You could absolutely position the p tag and then attach it to each corner of the parent `#fullContent > p {position: absolute; top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;}` Also make sure `#fullContent` has a position relative. But that seems really hacky. I might try the background image at that point.